# Need help on importing data into a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problems getting the data written to the database table. Everything works fine except for the last `mysql_query()` statement shown below:

```
   mysql_query("insert into $TableName (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link)
   values ('. implode(',', $queries)') or die(mysql_error()");
```

I am not an MySQL programmer and have been struggling for many hours trying to get this to work. The following code was put together based on suggestions from other forums via searching the web.

```
// --------------- Save Data to Database ---------------------

// Database Authentication-user, password
   $TableName = 'User_Data';
   $dbh = mysql_connect ("localhost", "username", "password")
   or die ('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());

   mysql_select_db ("database");

// Creates Database Table if it does not exist
   if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$TableName."'")) != 1) {
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $TableName(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    Topic varchar(300) NOT NULL default '',
    Date  varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    Phone_Number varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    Original_Description varchar(2000) NOT NULL default '',
    Alt_Description varchar(2000) NOT NULL default '',
    Website_Link  varchar(2000) NOT NULL default '') ") or die(mysql_error());
   }

// Write to MySQL Database
   $queries = array(); 
   for($i=0; $i<count($current_topic_array); $i++) {
    $queries[] = '('.$current_topic_array[$i].', '.$date_array[$i].', '.$phone_array[$i].', '.$original_description_array[$i].', '.$alt_description_array[$i].', '.$website_link_array[$i].')'; 
   }
   mysql_query("insert into $TableName (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link)
   values ('. implode(',', $queries)') or die(mysql_error()");
```

The database table gets created but no data gets written into the User_Data table. For testing purposes, I entered `echo $queries[$i];` into the `for($i=0; $i<count($current_topic_array); $i++)` loop to see if the data existed, and it does. The results of the echo was:

> (Classic Cars, 05-02-2012, 777-555-1212, Classic Car show held in Spring of May 2012, Classic Car May 2012, http‍://website.com/post/864.html)
>
> (Classic Cars, 07-13-2012, 777-555-5412, Classic Car show held in Summer of July 2012, Classic Car July 2012, http‍://website.com/post/865.html)

etc...

I also tried replacing the `mysql_query()` statement with the following three variations for entering the data into the table, but all three did not work too:

```
$query = "insert into (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link) values " . implode(", ", $queries);

$query = "insert into User_Data(Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link) values " . implode(", ", $queries);

$query = mysql_query("insert into $TableName (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link) 
values ('. implode(',', $queries)') or die(mysql_error()");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the output look like if you create your query as a string?  Can you run it from command line?  In other words, $query = "insert into insert into $TableName (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link) 
values ('. implode(',', $queries)') or die(mysql_error()"; What is the value of $query.  That should let you better understand what the query ends up looking like, and a full piece you can try to run manually as a proof of concept.

Comment: using echo $query; for $query = "insert into User_Data(Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link) values " . implode(", ", $queries); i get the following: insert into User_Data(Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link) values (Classic Cars, 05-02-2012, 777-555-1212, Classic Car show held in Spring of May 2012, Classic Car May 2012, http://website.com/post/864.html), (Classic Cars, 07-13-2012, 777-555-5412, Classic Car show held in Summer of July 2012, Classic Car July 2012, http://website.com/post/865.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Major edits to my original answer after re-reading**

Your line:

```
mysql_query("insert into $TableName (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description,   
   Alt_Description, Website_Link)
   values ('. implode(',', $queries)') or die(mysql_error()");
```

looks wrong, and might explain why you're not getting an error.  It should be:

```
mysql_query("insert into $TableName (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, 
   Alt_Description, Website_Link)
   values (". implode(',', $queries) . ")") or die(mysql_error());
```

In general, I would also argue that you'll find yourself in a better place to debug if you structured it more like this:

```
$query = "insert into $TableName (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, 
       Alt_Description, Website_Link)
       values (". implode(',', $queries) . ")";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

** was missing a semicolon ath the end of the first line in the above snippet. **
Then you've got the option of spitting out the exact query you used.

Comment: thanks, but that was the results of the echo $query; for $query = "insert into User_Data(Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link) values " . implode(", ", $queries);

Comment: the problem is with the following statement for importing the data into a table:        mysql_query("insert into $TableName (Topic, Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link)
       values ('. implode(',', $queries)') or die(mysql_error()");

Comment: your mysql_query() line causes the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' and the $query = "insert... line causes the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: Sorry.  Missed a semicolon (if you were referring to the last snippet).

Comment: I meant i tried both snippets, the mysql_query() one caused the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' and the $query = "insert into... one caused the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: Updated the mysql_query() to include a closing parenthesis.  Not sure why you're getting the parse error on the $query line, as I don't see anything wrong with it syntactically.

Comment: I tried both snippets again and got the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Classic Car show held in Spring of May 2012, Classic Car May 2' at line 2

Comment: Just to let you know, I really do appreciate all your help.

Comment: First question, same error for both?  If so, can you echo the $query variable just before executing the mysql_query statement?  It looks like you might not have a closing ' and opening ' between your original_desc and alt_desc for the events.

Comment: OK, here is the echo of the echo $queries[$i]; inside the loop and the error:

Comment: (Classic Cars, 05-02-2012, 777-555-1212, Classic Car show held in Spring of May 2012 (los angeles), Classic Car May 2012 (los angeles), http://website.com/post/864.html)(Classic Cars, 07-13-2012, 777-555-5412, Classic Car show held in Summer of July 2012 (los angeles), Classic Car July 2012 (los angeles), http://website.com/post/865.html)You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Car show held in Spring of May 2012 (los angeles), Classic Car May 2012 (los angeles), http://webs' at line 2

Comment: I think we end up back at my original suggestion that the problem is now part of the query building.  Each string needs to be inside a tick mark (single quote).  I.e. it should start ('Classic Cars',05-02-2102,'777-555-1212'....

Comment: OK added the tick mark, so I now get  ('Classic Cars',05-02-2102,'777-555-1212'.... but now the error is Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: I finially got it to work. I changed the for loop items to: "'.mysql_real_escape_string($current_topic_array[$i]).'", and then changed the mysql_query to: mysql_query("INSERT INTO $TableName (Topic, Post_Date, Phone_Number, Original_Description, Alt_Description, Website_Link) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql)); btw... had to change the word Date to Post_Date since Date is a reserved word. Thanks, for all your help.